# What parts do I need to use Di2 wireless shifting on a road bike

Tags: shimano, shimano-di2

Also what is the cheapest best way to buy them. I just want everything that is absolutely necessary for wireless shifting so no crank, drive chain breaks etc.

Comment: If you want wireless shifting you're not talking "cheap".  And electronic shifting has little to do with the crank or chain.

Comment: That's ok it's for a research project. I just want to know what parts I need to get to test the wireless shifting separately from everything else.

Comment: So you don't want to test it on a bike?  Keep in mind that you need crank & chain motion to do any shifting, even if electronic.

Comment: A couple of hours of hindsight and I see my answer answers your stated question.  However, I'm still unsure why you want this.  Can you expand on the background?  We may be able to make more useful suggestions knowing the context.

Comment: Check the compatibility of your frame. Though Di2 can be made to fit any road frame - it can be aesthetically ugly with battery and wires externally mounted. (Step in SRAM eTap wireless)

Comment: Does Shimano even offer fully wireless shifting? As far as I know SRAM eTAP is the only true wireless shifting setup right now. Di2 can wireless sync to your computer, but uses junction boxes and wires to transmit the actual shifting commands.

Comment: Di2 is not wireless. Nothing like that exist. Didn't you mix it up with SRAM?

Comment: @JamieA,@Carel looks like I misunderstood that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You require these items, all DI2 compatible:

- rear derailleur mechanism
- di2 controller box (normally strapped to the bottom of your stem)
- di2 brifters, or di2 shift buttons that strap to your handlebars, but mean you can keep using your brifters as plain brakes.
- battery (one for a wired system, or several for a wireless system)
- wiring harness, and secure method of holding wiring on/in the frame so its protected.
- wall charger (maybe USB based, maybe a separate wall charger)

You probably require

- front derailleur mech unless you want to make it a 1x bike

For your testing, you really will need a road bike too.  The derailleurs will try to calibrate themselves and may go into fault mode if there's not a cassette or chainring detected.   So that means a modern cassette with 11 gears, maybe 10 (I'm unsure on this point)

Generally speaking, the whole groupset will cost about the same as a bike with that groupset fitted.  Used bike gear drops in price very fast too, so don't think you'll get your money back by selling it on after the testing, even if its never been ridden.

An alternative suggestion might be to make contact with the Shimano distributor in your area and see if you can get access to test/demo kit for your purposes.  As long as you're not cutting out a reseller, they might be happy to talk.  Or involve a LBS